# SQL Update statement: OperationalError near "FROM"

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

Replacing `box =` with `tb.box =` shifts the error to the '.':

```
query = (f'UPDATE tb '
         f"SET box = '{box_update}' "
         f'FROM {table} tb '
         'INNER JOIN question qu ON qu.id = tb.question_id '
         f'WHERE qu.number_a = {num_a} AND qu.number_b = {num_b};')
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "FROM": syntax error [SQL: "UPDATE tb SET box = '0' FROM addition tb INNER JOIN question qu ON qu.id = tb.question_id WHERE qu.number_a = 1 AND qu.number_b = 9;"]
```

Comment: What is your underlying SQL database (e.g. Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: What version of SQLite do you use? Since 3.33 SQLite supports this (2020-08-14).

Comment: ```sqlite3 is already the newest version (3.29.0-2ubuntu0.3).```

Comment: Please provide fuller code block including `connect` line and all `import` lines for a [mcve]. Also be sure to look into SQL parameterization to avoid any F-string interpolation.

Comment: I've updated sqlit3 to 3.33 but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual implementation may not be fully adhered even with latest SQLite to support UPDATE-FROM. Specifically, [docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) do not indicate:

- `JOIN` in outer query is supported in `UPDATE`.
- `FROM` table should not repeat table in `UPDATE`.
- Table alias alone in `UPDATE` may not be allowed. Possibly no alias for updated table should be used.

Consider below adjustment aligned to example in docs. Below demonstrates parameterization with `sqlite3` raw cursor. Adjust to however you run with sqlalchemy.

```py
q = f'''UPDATE {table}
        SET box = ? 
        FROM question qu 
        WHERE qu.id = {table}.question_id
          AND qu.number_a = ?
          AND qu.number_b = ?;
     '''

cursor.execute(q, (box_update, num_a, num_b))
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the update syntax you are using either is not supported at all, or at least is not supported on your version of SQLite.  However, you may rewrite your update to use exists logic:

```
query = (f'UPDATE {table} tb '
         f"SET box = '{box_update}' "
         f'WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM question qu '
         f'              WHERE qu.id = tb.question_id AND '
         f'                    qu.number_a = {num_a} AND qu.number_b = {num_b});')
```

The raw SQL query would look something like this:

```
UPDATE yourTable tb
SET box = ?
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM question qu
              WHERE qu.id = tb.question_id AND
                    qu.number_a = ? AND qu.number_b = ?);
```

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "tb": syntax error [SQL: "UPDATE addition tb SET box = '0' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM question qu WHERE qu.id = tb.question_id AND qu.number_a = 1 AND qu.number_b = 8);"]